# Find Tangents to a Rotated Translated Ellipse at 2 points through which a straight line passes.

Tags: calculus, geometry, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

[This image (view in this link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SGlT.jpg) is a problem I can't seem to complete (for a personal project).

I have a 2D array of points (or pixels) that represent an ellipse and I'm trying to to find tangents to the ellipse at 2 points on the ellipse (through which a straight line passes not necessarily parallel to the horizontal). See picture for an understanding of the problem.

I can't seem to figure this out because of the rotation. I imagine it would involve a change in coordinate systems perhaps (I may be wrong).

Comment: btw water ( and mercury ) drops have higher curvature at bottom contact areas compared to points at top,

Comment: Is the problem posed as posed correct?

Answer (score 0):

The general equation of an ellipse, like other conics, is given by a 2nd degree equation that can be given the form:

$$ax^2+2bxy+cy^2+2dx+2ey+1=0 \tag{1}$$

depending on $5$ unknown parameters.

One needs $5$ equations for determining them. These equations will be obtained by finding $5$ points of the ellipse, the first two of them $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ being the points of intersection with the line.

Once you have solved the linear system, i.e., obtained $a,b,c,d,e$, it is easy to obtain the equations of the tangent by the a kind of bilinear form associated to the "kind of" quadratic expression (1):

$$ax_kx+b(xy_k+x_ky)+cy_ky+d(x+x_k)+e(y+y_k)+1=0 \ \ \ \text{for} \ \ k=1,2\tag{2}$$

Remark 1: how to take points $P_3,P_4,P_5$ ? The most apart one from the other... It is clear that taking different points will give (slightly) different equations for the ellipse.

Remark 2: The last term "1" in equation (1) is arbitrary ; it could be any non-zero coefficient; for example, if we replace "1" by "5", with the same points we would obtain values for $(a,b,c,d,e)$ that are five times the values found with "1". We cannot replace "1" by "0" because it would force the ellipse to pass through the origin, which is not the case here (I think you take the origin on the lower left of the picture).

---

(Not essential at all for your study)

Remark 3: Explanation of the "kind of" : the "true" quadratic form is the so-called homogeneized version of (1)

$$ax^2+2bxy+cy^2+2dxt+2eyt+t^2=0 \tag{3}$$

and its "true" associated bilinar form (generalized dot product) is:

$$ax_kx+b(xy_k+x_ky)+cy_ky+d(xt_k+x_kt)+e(yt+y_kt)+tt_k=0\tag{4}$$

being understood that we set $t=t_k=1$ for retrieving (1) from (3) and (2) from (4).

Comment: To then find tangents, would I need to find the partial derivative of (4), could you explain that part.

Comment: But you already have the tangents equations with equation (2)!... You just need to wite it into the following form: $(ax_k+by_k+d)x +  (bx_k+cy_k+e)y + (dx_k+ey_k+1)=0$ where indeed you can retrieve partial derivatives but you don't need them.

Comment: If you want to understand the why and how of equation (2) and how it is connected to partial derivatives, see the detailed explanations [here](https://www.toppr.com/content/story/amp/tangent-to-parabola-at-a-given-point-ii-71743/)

Comment: Please say if you have succeded...

Comment: Yes, thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Comment only. Is this the problem statement?

[image]

From a fully defined inclined ellipse two points (say D,A) are selected on it. Equations of two tangents from them are required.